# kubernetes configMapRef merge issue

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

Why kubernetes merge config maps?
I have deployment config

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
    spec:
      containers:
            - configMapRef:
                name: **testa**-env
```

My config map testa-env looks

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
data:
  AAAA: testA
```

Also i have another deployment in same namespace with config map BBB: testB
Then i go to my pods and make export and see that configs has been merged?! On podA i see both configs

```
podA> export

AAAA: testA
BBBB: testB
```

Also looks output on pod B.
So another developer can steal all config not for his project!
I have been rechecked this on 3 different clusters and have same result

Comment: Just as you've described it, simply creating a second ConfigMap shouldn't cause a Deployment's environment to change if it doesn't reference that ConfigMap at all.  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], with correct Kubernetes YAML that demonstrates the problem?  In the last example, what sort of CLI are you running, and how does it produce its output data?

Comment: I wrote example and it works. I wrote more complex example with helm and it works too. I try to run two deployments at one time - it works. Configs not merged. But i see them merged on production. I can't figure out how and where it happens. You are right my question not really correct and more complex